# Salvaged magnetic materials for low performance 1MHz boost converter

Tags: rf, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, flyback, magnetics

I am wondering if I could modify a MT3608 boost module by winding a custom inductor / transformer for it, to generate a kV range voltage (at sub mA current).

I'm thinking of replacing the 22uH inductor with a transformer with a similar primary inductance and turns ratio of about 10:1 for a step up voltage of a few hundred volts. Page 14 of https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/609/lt1304-1504180.pdf (LT1304) shows the kind of scheme I want to attempt, the top circuit with the Cockcroft-Walton multiplier on the output (my application is for a photomultiplier tube for a scintillation counter). I doubt I can legally copy that image here but essentially its just a standard boost converter with a flyback transformer instead of a inductor.

I only need a few hundred microamps output.

The MT3608 runs at around 1.3MHz which is higher than I have experience with.

Would trying some ferrite rod material be a decent start? Or should I be looking at a bobbin, very small E core, etc. I've got plenty of old magnetics around here, but most of them are much larger than what I imagine I would need - the smallest probably half an inch to an inch cubed. Would it be a problem to use a much larger core than is needed? I realise I need an air gap, but since I am not trying to get high power through a minimally sized ferrite, can I just use a bit of ferrite rod for instance?

Comment: Getting low interwinding capacitance for SRF >> 1.3MHz will be a learning experience ! on the secondary.

Comment: Why not simply step up line voltage and rectify then filter and regulate

Comment: Its for a battery application - I need around 1.5kV at about 200uA from a battery

Comment: HV and HF cause more problems than necessary.  try what you know how. 50 kHz sine AC step up then rectify, filter.  What EMI emission levels are needed? Sine boost requires no shielding

Comment: 1.3 MHz sounds impractial for me

Comment: I see what you mean re self resonance. Re the sine, step up, rectify etc - to get really low battery drain the thing needs to be discontinuous I think, so it means reinventing the wheel of the boost converter chip really. I also need very low noise and ripple, so feedback control. But yea, 1.3 MHz is way out of my experience and seems a challenge.

Comment: CHoose a simple audio power oscillator and step up transformer x30 to x100 and compute impedances then vary the attenuation of audio for regulation with feedback and bufferfor current gain

Comment: “Low performance” and “1.3 MHz” doesn’t really sound synonymous.

Comment: To get kV even at 50kHz you're probably looking at a resonant converter.

Answer (score 3):

You should "perhaps" try something like this.
As example. Note that the voltage supply can adjust the High Voltage needed.
Average current simulated until 2 mA.
Be sure to check all component's specifications ...

[image]